# Oracle: Usage the CONNECT BY statement without START WITH

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some difficulties in the usage of the CONNECT BY statement with Oracle. I have no problem in writing the query for 1 given record (using START WITH) but I'm looking for a possibility to create an extract.

**Data**

1
   2
       3
       4
   5
   6

**Table**
ID    PARENT_ID
1     2
1     5
1     6
2     3
2     4

What I need is a table which would be filled with the following information/records.

**Desired Output**
ID    PARENT_ID
1     2
1     3
1     4
1     5
1     6
2     3
2     4

If I use the following query

```
SELECT PARENT_ID
FROM TABLE
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
```

I will have the following result

2
3
4
5
6
This is effectively the parent_id's which I am looking for for ID 1.

If I remove the start with I have the following list

2
3
4
5
6
3
4

I've tried to add the ID in the statement but that did not work either. Any idea if it's possible to have such an output?

Comment: Can you specify which value belongs to which column? It seems like your table doesn't contain any item with ID = 1. Or it contain 5 of them.

Comment: Just add "connect_by_root id"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `prior` keyword. You want to connect the parent_id to the id of the previous record. (Could be the other way around, but you'll notice that fast enough. ;-) )

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY prior ID = PARENT_ID
```